# wxSizer с его содержимым не подстраивается под размер родительского окна

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
 gFrame = new MyFrame( NULL, myframe_window_title, position, new_frame_size, app_style ); 
    gSizer1 = new wxGridSizer(0, 2, 0, 0);
    wxPanel *m_Page1 = new wxPanel(gFrame, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL);
    gSizer1->Add(m_Page1, 1, wxEXPAND , 5);
    wxPanel *m_panel2 = new wxPanel(gFrame, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL);
    gSizer1->Add(m_panel2, 1, wxEXPAND , 5);
    gFrame->SetSizer(gSizer1);
    gFrame->Layout();
```

При увеличении размера родительского окна, дочерние элементы своего не меняют, а лишь "размазываются" как на  скриншоте. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При попытке изменить размер дочерней панели вручную, приложение тут же крашится.

Comment: Не могу считать себя серьезным специалистом в wx, но для начала я бы предложил сделать 2 вещи: 1) для фрейма сделать обработчик события  `EVT_SIZE` - это оно должно заниматься корректной перерисовкой окна при изменении размера (и без реализации обработчика будет как раз такой эффект как на рисунке); 2) обычно при использовании сайзеров wxSmith (редактор окошек из Code::Blocks) после назначения главного сайзера окна добавляет еще два вызова: 
`gSizer1->Fit(this);
gSizer1->SetSizeHints(this);`

Comment: В любом случае будет полезно привести минимальный код для воспроизведения ошибки.